# Does Poltergeist (2015) have any connection with the original Poltergeist series?

Tags: poltergeist, poltergeist-2015

Is the Poltergeist (2015) movie related to the original Poltergeist series?

Comment: Its a remake of the original film from 1982

Answer (score 3):

Source [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poltergeist_(2015_film)) :

> Poltergeist is a 2015 American 3D supernatural horror film directed by
>   Gil Kenan, written by David Lindsay-Abaire, and produced by Roy Lee &
>   Sam Raimi. **A remake of the 1982 film of the same name**, the film stars
>   Sam Rockwell, Rosemarie DeWitt, Jared Harris, and Jane Adams. It was
>   released on May 22, 2015, by 20th Century Fox and Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer.
>   The film grossed over $95 million worldwide.